# In SapUI5 or OpenUI5 simple.GanttChartContainer, how can I have selected shapes hilight properly?

Tags: sapui5, gantt-chart

In SAPUI5 simple.GanttChartContainer, I have set up a custom row settings object for all of my differing object types, projects.. tasks... milestones... icons. I used the same technique as in this example:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.gantt.simple.GanttChartWithTable/sample/sap.gantt.sample.GanttChart2Shapes

Prior to this I used shapes1 aggregation, which did show selection borders automatically.

Does anybody know how to have the chart shapeSelectionSettings be applied to shapes in my custom aggregations? Or any other explanation as to why these selection borders are not showing up?

I've spent some time simplifying and backtracking - here's my view. Currently, even though Resize and Connect are both enabled and hooked up to event handlers and my BaseRectangles are resizable and connectable, selections are not drawn, connector boxes are not drawn and the EW cursor does not appear when hovering over a resize handle. The controller is only setting up axis and loading data. I have no idea whatsoever why this has stopped working - I've even tried earlier versions of SAPUI5.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<View
    xmlns="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns:m="sap.m"
  xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:gnt2="sap.gantt.simple"
  xmlns:projectpro="ProjectPro.controller"
  xmlns:gnt-cal="sap.gantt.def.cal"
  xmlns:axistime="sap.gantt.axistime"
    controllerName="ProjectPro.controller.MasterPlanning"
  id="MasterPlanningMain">

    <m:Page xmlns="sap.ui.table" title="{branding>/ProductName} Master Planning" showNavButton="false" contentOnlyBusy="true">
      <gnt2:GanttChartContainer id="container" enableTimeScrollSync="true">

        <!--Activities/Milestones/Relationships-->
        <gnt2:GanttChartWithTable id="ActivityView"
            shapeSelectionMode = "Single"
            shapeSelectionSettings="{color: 'red', strokeDasharray:'1,0'}"
            class="sapUiSizeCondensed"
            shapeResize="activities_shapeResize"
            shapeConnect="activities_shapeConnect"
            >
          <gnt2:table>
            <TreeTable
              selectionMode="None"
              visibleRowCountMode="Auto"
              rows="{
                          path: 'plandata>/data',
                parameters: { arrayNames: [ 'children' ] }
              }">
              <rowSettingsTemplate>
              <gnt2:GanttRowSettings rowId="{id}" relationships="{ path:'plandata>/links', templateShareable: 'true' }">
                  <gnt2:BaseRectangle 
                    shapeId="{plandata>id}"
                    time="{plandata>start_date}"
                    endTime="{plandata>end_date}"
                    resizable="true"
                    selectable="true"
                    draggable= "true"
                    connectable="true"
                    title="{plandata>text}" showTitle="true"
                    tooltip=""
                    fill="#4cc"
                    />
                <gnt2:relationships>
                  <gnt2:Relationship shapeId="{plandata>id}"
                  predecessor="{plandata>source}" successor="{plandata>target}" type="{plandata>gantttype}" tooltip="{= ${plandata>display_link} }"
                  selectable="true" />
                </gnt2:relationships>
              </gnt2:GanttRowSettings>
              </rowSettingsTemplate>

              <!--Tree Table Columns-->
              <Column sortProperty="text" filterProperty="text" width="30em">
                <m:Text text="Activity" wrapping="false"/>
                <template>
                  <m:Input value="{= ${plandata>text} }" change="nodeRenamed" class="activity_text" />
                </template>
              </Column>
            </TreeTable>
          </gnt2:table>
        </gnt2:GanttChartWithTable>
      </gnt2:GanttChartContainer>
    </m:Page>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked through this issue, and found that the `rowId` binding on `GanttRowSettings` was the problem. This was bound to `{id}` and my data model is at `{plandata>}`, so it should have been `{plandata>id}` - changing this value fixed the problem.

Even though not binding this `rowId` completely breaks a built in behaviour (selected shape highlighting), SAP UI5 does not output any errors or warnings to the console suggesting that anything is wrong with Selection rendering, so there's really nothing to go on when it goes wrong.